# How to assign a hotkey to a menu item in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, phpunit, hotkeys

I have `Eclipse for PHP Developers` based on `Helios`.

In order to run my PHPUnit tests on a directory its:

- right click
- click
- click
- click

[image]

**How can I assign keyboard hotkey (e.g. `ALT-Apple-P`) to "Run PHPUnit Test" based on a certain directory so I can execute my tests without all the clicking.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the eclipse preferences. Ther you go to `General -> Keys`. In that window you must search for your *Run PHPUnit Test* command an binding your key combination!

Answer (score 0):

Menu Window -> Preferences: General -> Keys: Search in the list the action you intend to bind a shortcut to, below on the Binding set the shortcut, and you're done.